# How to capture UIImage of the visible part of tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I am first to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.
I want to capture the visible part of the tableView to an UIImage and let it to the content of a new CALayer.
Here is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tableView.frame.size);

[tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect frame = [self.view.window convertRect:view.frame fromView:tableView.superview];
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
imageLayer.frame = frame;
```

However, if I scroll down the tableView, the top part of captured image will be white.
I use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);` to see the result.

After longtime finding the answer, I have to ask this question here, hope someone can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: What version(s) of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: Instead of `[view.layer renderInContext` have you tried `[tableView.layer renderInContext`?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw sorry for my mistake, the `view` is the `tableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a view called "viewHolder", set it's "clipsToBounds" to yes. Add tableView as a subview to viewHolder. Now use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewHolder.frame.size);

[viewHolder.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```